# what is the easy way to make suffix from this js code?

Tags: javascript, trie, patricia-trie

Note the code below shows the array in the console, not in the snippet output

```js
var nodes = ["maria", "mary", "marks", "michael"];

function insert_word(split_nodes) {
  var rest = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < split_nodes.length; i++) {
    //console.log(current);
    var word = split_nodes[i];
    var letters = word.split("");
    var current = rest;
    console.log(current);
    for (var j = 0; j < letters.length; j++) {
      var character = letters[j];
      var position = current[character];
      if (position == null) {
        current = current[character] = j == letters.length - 1 ? 0 : {};
      } else {
        current = current[character];
      }
    }
  }
}
insert_word(nodes);
```

Above outputs this

```
M :{a : {r :{i :{a :0},
    k :0,   
    y :
    },
},
    i :{c :{h :{a :{e :{l :0}}}}}}}
```

but I want to output this :

```
M :{ar:{ia:0,
    k :0,   
    y :0
    },
 ichael :0
}
```

can anyone help me to find out this output from my code? how could i make suffeix from this code?

Comment: the output is invalid syntax

Comment: @mplungjan my code is okay. when i run it on my local machine it gives me output which i wrote at the top. can you help me. thanks

Comment: what do you do with words who is a substring from another word, like `'marc'` and `'marcus'`?

Comment: it will take the common letters from the words for compress the search.

Comment: The output shows in weird empty arrays in the console.

Comment: can you clear your cache and load the page again? @  mplungjan

Comment: Not needed. It does work but the console.log is really weird. A JSON.stringify of the actual object would be better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution take a sightly changed object structure for the end indicator with a property `isWord`, because the original structure does not reflect entries like `'marc'` and `'marcus'`, because if only `'marc'` is uses, a zero at the end of the tree denotes the end of the word, but it does not allowes to add a substring, because the property is a primitive and not an object.

Basically this solution creates first a comlete tree with single letters and then joins all properties which have only one children object.

```js
function join(tree) {
    Object.keys(tree).forEach(key => {
        var object = tree[key],
            subKeys = Object.keys(object),
            joinedKey = key,
            found = false;    

        if (key === 'isWord') {
            return;
        }
        while (subKeys.length === 1 && subKeys[0] !== 'isWord') {
            joinedKey += subKeys[0];
            object = object[subKeys[0]];
            subKeys = Object.keys(object);
            found = true;
        }
        if (found) {
            delete tree[key];
            tree[joinedKey] = object;
        }
        join(tree[joinedKey]);
    });
}

var node = ["maria", "mary", "marks", "michael"],
    tree = {};

node.forEach(string => [...string].reduce((t, c) => t[c] = t[c] || {}, tree).isWord = true);
console.log(tree);

join(tree);
console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

---

A recursive single pass approach with a function for inserting a word into a tree which updates the nodes.

It works by

- Checking the given `string` with all keys of the object and if `string` start with the actual key, then a recursive call with the part string and the nested part of the trie is made.
- Otherwise, it checks how many characters are the same from the key and the string.

  Then it checks the counter and creates a new node with the common part and two nodes, the old node content and a new node for the string.

  Because of the new node, the old node is not more necessary and gets deleted, as well as the iteration stops by returning `true` for the `update` check.
- If no update took place, a new property with string as key and zero as value is assigned.

```js
function insertWord(tree, string) {
    var keys = Object.keys(tree),
        updated = keys.some(function (k) {
            var i = 0;

            if (string.startsWith(k)) {
                insertWord(tree[k], string.slice(k.length));
                return true;
            }
            while (k[i] === string[i] && i < k.length) {
                i++;
            }
            if (i) {
                tree[k.slice(0, i)] = { [k.slice(i)]: tree[k], [string.slice(i)]: 0 };
                delete tree[k];
                return true;
            }
        });

    if (!updated) {            
        tree[string] = 0;
    }
}

var words = ["maria", "mary", "marks", "michael"],
    tree = {};

words.forEach(insertWord.bind(null, tree));
console.log(tree);

insertWord(tree, 'mara');
console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: you did a great job for me. can you help me one more? i want my output as like which i added into my question. it will dynamically change.

Comment: the dynamic change is much more complex as it look like. actually i have no idea how to tackle that.

Comment: than i just only need the out put as like that. can i contact with you?                       
 M :{ar:{ia:0,
    k :0,   
    y :0
    },
 ichael :0
}

Comment: @Hey Nina Scholz God of javascript, how can i use keyup function for this function to retrieve the value? if i press "m" all the values of "m" will show and if i press "s" all the values of "s" will show below. Thanks

Comment: @rai, that is a completely different question, you may ask.

Comment: i asked but no one reply or help me to findout the result. Thanks